# Issue with APP Service Plan in a Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal, azure-app-service-plans

I'm not trying to delete any App Service Plan or App Service, But I'm seeing “**This resource has a 'delete' lock that prevents us from deleting the
resource. Please remove the lock and try again.**” message on our App Service Plans under one Resource Group, Other Resource Group App Service Plans are fine.
All App Services are working fine under faulty Resource Group.

While Creating Dashboard using Faulty Resource Group, App Service Plans and App Services are not visible.

Please guide fixing this issue.

[image: This resource has a 'delete' lock that prevents us from deleting the resource.Please remove the lock and try again.]

[image: App Service Plans and App Services not Populating here]

Comment: Have you tried removing the resource lock?  Or did someone else create the resource for you, and locked it so it couldn't be deleted?

Comment: I've created resources and locks, I'm not trying to delete any resources, still showing this message.

Comment: @VIJAYRAAVI If you clean your browser cache and refresh your browser, the issue still exist? Also, I suggest you could test by other browser.

Comment: Tried in different browsers, machines & accounts. BTW, App Service Plans and App Services are not loading under Dashboard Tile Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Resource locks don't just prevent deletion. There are two types of locks: CanNotDelete and ReadOnly. If a ReadOnly lock is applied, you won't be able to make administrative changes to the resource. I suggest clearing the locks and seeing if this message goes away.

Comment: I have not applied ReadOnly lock to any resource. Created new App Service with new App Service Plan, For new App Service Plan also it is showing same message which has no locks applied.

Comment: If you have no resource locks applied to any resources in the resource group and are seeing this message, you should probably open a support ticket with Microsoft.